# useSelector doesn't load the state in time

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a project of mine using `React` and `Redux`.

I'm trying to retrieve the `token` field from my `auth` state from my store (which contains an authentication key that I intend to send over to my server side) using `useSelector`but the thing is, that **it doesn't load in time**. How do I fix this?

I'll add below parts of my code that are associated with this issue:

LikeButton.js: (here is the part where I'm trying to retrieve token)

```
...

const LikeButton = ({ postId }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(false);
  const isMount = useIsMount();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { token } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { likedPostsIds } = useSelector((state) => state.likes);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) dispatch(fetchLikedPosts(token));
  }, [token]);

...
```

likeActions.js:

```
...

export const fetchLikedPosts = ({ token }) => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: fetchLikedPostsQuery(),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())

...
```

authActions.js

```
...

export const signIn = ({ password, email }) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: IS_AUTH_LOADING,
  });
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: signInQuery(password, email),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resData) => {
      if (resData.errors) {
        dispatch(showNotification("User authentication has failed!", ERROR));
        dispatch({
          type: AUTH_ERROR,
        });
      } else {
        setLocalStorageAuth(resData.data.signIn.token, expiryDate);
        dispatch({
          type: SIGN_IN,
          payload: resData.data.signIn,
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        showNotification(
          "User authentication has failed. Please try again later.",
          ERROR
        )
      );
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
      });
      emptyLocalStorage();
    });
};
...
```

auth.js:

```
...

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
  isAuth: localStorage.getItem("isAuth"),
  expiryDate: localStorage.getItem("expiryDate"),
  isLoading: false,
};

export default function authReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_LOADING:
    case IS_AUTH_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case SIGN_IN:
      return {
        token: action.payload.token,
        isAuth: true,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        token: null,
        isAuth: false,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    case CREATE_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

...
```

Comment: Doesn't load in time for what?  To render part of your component?

Comment: @SethLutske when i use dispatch(fetchLikedPosts(token) then the token sent is undefined

Comment: @SethLutske nope, that's valid JavaScript

Comment: I think your useEffect would be called twice. Once upon initialization with the value undefined for '`token` and once with the value from your useSelector(). If your token doesn't have a value in the second iteraition there might be something wrongg with your useSelector()

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: What do the redux dev tools say? What actions are dispatched and what changes do they cause? If auth is not set then maybe check if auth is loading before dispatching fetchLikedPosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchLikedPosts` function expects an object with a `token` key as an argument. the effect currently passes just the `token` as an argument. Try

```
  useEffect(() => {
     // note the change from token to {token}
    if (token) dispatch(fetchLikedPosts({token}));
  }, [token]);
```